# jQuery $.each loop and json data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, each

I can't seem to get this working, i am retrieving some json data, and just trying to loop through it an append it to a DIV. here is my code:

**HOW THE JSON IS RETURNED (PHP)**

```
{"list":[{"subscribe":"example"},{"subscribe":"example2"},{"subscribe":"example3"},{"subscribe":"example4"},{"subscribe":"example5"}]}
```

**MY JSON CALL USING JQUERY**

```
$.getJSON("article.php",function(data)
   $.each(data.list, function(i,data) {
      var listData = "<li>" + data.subscribe + "</li>";
      $('#lists').append(listData);
   });
});
```

I am not retrieving any errors in the console, but nothing is happening, i know the call is successful, am i doing the .each loop correctly? can anyone please help?

Comment: Have you tried sticking a `console.log` before your iterative loop to see what `data` is returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you can try this:

```
$.each(data.list, function(i, item) {
    var listData = "<li>" + item.subscribe + "</li>";
    $('#lists').append(listData);
});
```

Just change `function(i, data)` to `function(i, item)`.

By reusing the variable name `data` in the way that you are, you are not actually looping through the array as you expect to.

Answer (score 2):

I personally haven't used `$.each` to loop through an array because I always just do a `for` loop, so you can try this:

```
$.getJSON("article.php", function (d) {
    var listsDiv = $("#lists");

    for (var i = 0; i < d.list.length; i++) {
        listsDiv.append("<li>" + d.list[i].subscribe + "</li>");
    };
});
```

I'm 99% confident that it should work for what you need. Also, it's better to have a variable to your div outside of the loop and append in the loop because right now your code is traversing the DOM for that div for *each* object in your JSON list.

Also, I'm not sure if you're truncating the JSON response, but you may want to attach a 'success' property and check for that. So you're code would be upgraded to this:

```
$.getJSON("article.php", function (d) {
    if (d.success) {
        var listsDiv = $("#lists");

        for (var i = 0; i < d.list.length; i++) {
            listsDiv.append("<li>" + d.list[i].subscribe + "</li>");
        };
    } else {
        // Do something else to notify the user that the data could not be retrieved.
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems you got a syntax error. A { is missing after first line i.e the starting { for "function(data)" in first line

Comment: +1 Or it's a bad copy/paste, but never the less it's missing. Good job finding that, I looked right passed it, lol...