# How to display JSON data containing arrays using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, each

This is the JSON that is returned from my PHP

```
{
"17":{"answer_id":"17","answer":"You earn a salary","is_correct":"N"},
"18":{"answer_id":"18","answer":"You earn profit","is_correct":"N"},
"19":{"answer_id":"19","answer":"You invest money","is_correct":"N"},
"20":{"answer_id":"20","answer":"All of the above.","is_correct":"Y"}
}
```

So I basically need to loop through this and display them as radio button options.
But I'm stuck - I checked out this solution
[jQuery $.each loop and json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973717/help-with-jquery-each-loop-and-json-data)

But that is just one array and also the other issue I have is with the key being a number.

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: How do you want to map the JSON data to the radio button? (what do you want to become the radio buttons ID, value, name, label etc?)

Comment: what will be markup for you radio buttons?

Comment: You might find it easier/simpler/just as effective to have PHP output the HTML and use `$('#target_element').load()` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ret = {
"17":{"answer_id":"17","answer":"You earn a salary","is_correct":"N"},
"18":{"answer_id":"18","answer":"You earn profit","is_correct":"N"},
"19":{"answer_id":"19","answer":"You invest money","is_correct":"N"},
"20":{"answer_id":"20","answer":"All of the above.","is_correct":"Y"}
};

$.each(ret, function(key, value) {

   var radio_with_label = $('<label for="'+ value.answer_id +'">'+ value.answer +'</label><input name="'+ key +'" id="'+ value.answer_id +'" type="radio" value="'+ value.is_correct+'">');

   $(TARGET).append(radio_with_label); // TARGET -> any valid selector container to radios
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response - worked perfectly :) - I had spent 2 hours figuring that out

Comment: Be careful here, as you will be generating `id`s that begin with a number, which is not technically allowed (although for most browsers it works just fine, except IE of course). You may wish to prepend some character data: 'id_', that will give you valid markup.

Comment: Thanks Daniel - I did prepend answerid_ - but thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {
    "17": {
        "answer_id": "17",
        "answer": "You earn a salary",
        "is_correct": "N"
    },
    "18": {
        "answer_id": "18",
        "answer": "You earn profit",
        "is_correct": "N"
    },
    "19": {
        "answer_id": "19",
        "answer": "You invest money",
        "is_correct": "N"
    },
    "20": {
        "answer_id": "20",
        "answer": "All of the above.",
        "is_correct": "Y"
    }
}

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    $('#content').append('<input id="rad-'+key+'" type="radio" name="contnet" value="'+key+'"><label for="rad-'+key+'">'+value.answer+'</label><br>');
});​
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/nnrjs/)

Comment: here I don't care about the **is_correct** value, because is not clear what you want to de with it.

Comment: Thanks for the demo - the first solution worked - so accepted that answer. Thanks for the time

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="../../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var data = {
                "17": { "answer_id": "17", "answer": "You earn a salary", "is_correct": "N" },
                "18": { "answer_id": "18", "answer": "You earn profit", "is_correct": "N" },
                "19": { "answer_id": "19", "answer": "You invest money", "is_correct": "N" },
                "20": { "answer_id": "20", "answer": "All of the above.", "is_correct": "Y" }
            };

            $.each(data, function (i, entity) {
                $('#radioButtonList').append($('<input />', { 'type': 'radio', 'name': 'answerRadioButtonList', 'id': entity.answer_id, 'value': entity.is_correct })).append(entity.answer + '<br />');
            });

            $('#radioButtonList').find(':radio').live('click', function () {
                if ($(this).val() === 'Y') {
                    alert('Correct Answre.');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="radioButtonList">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - and for creating the demo - appreciate your time - I've given you an up vote - but accepted the first answer as that worked too - Thanks again